# Ruby - convert from symbol to variable

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How can I convert :obj back into a variable called obj inside the def?

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.some_method_call
end

foo :obj
```

**UPDATE**:
The final code is more elaborate than this but...

I like to be able to say

```
foo :obj
```

instead of

```
foo obj
```

I working on some DSL-like syntax. And this one change would let things read a little clearer.

Comment: Does this mean your symbol, represented inside bar, directly corresponds to an instance variable?

Answer (score 13):

What kind of variable is `obj` in your example? If it's a local variable of the scope where foo is called, it can't be accessed from inside foo, unless you pass the current binding as a second parameter.

If you want to access the instance variable `@obj`, it's easy:

```
def foo(bar)
  instance_variable_get("@#{bar}").length
end

@obj = "lala"
foo("obj") #=> 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use eval

```
def foo(bar)
  eval(bar.to_s).some_method_call
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit odd, but if you are willing to pass an empty block (or if you are passing one anyway), you can get the binding from the block, then call `eval` and pass the binding:

```
def foo(symbol, &block)
  binding = block.send(:binding)

  eval(symbol.to_s, binding)
end

var = 3

puts foo(:var) {}
```

This will print 3.

Alternatively, ActiveSupport apparently has something called Binding.of_caller that you may be able to use so you don't have to pass the block, but I don't know how well it works.

Another alternative is to call foo and pass the binding in:

```
def foo(binding, symbol)
  eval(symbol.to_s, binding)
end

binding = self.send(:binding)
var = 3

puts foo(binding, :var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the variable or the accessor method?  Sepp2k gave the name for an instance variable; for an accessor use

```
def foo(bar)
  self.send(bar).some_method_call
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly can't. That definition won't have access to the calling scope's local variables. If you want to explain a little more fully what you're trying to do, we might be able to offer a useful alternative.